# Node InversifyJS - Implementing middleware in all routes

Tags: node.js, inversifyjs

In the documentation for *Inversify Express Utils*, the example shows how to override `BaseMiddleware` and then to inject it into a particular route in a controller as shown [here](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-utils#basemiddleware).

Is there a way to inject the middleware into every route without specifically including it in each `@httpX` decorator?

Comment: What have you tryed at this point?

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier Here's an example: https://github.com/kaiserapps/hacda-money-api/blob/master/src/api/controllers/foo.controller.ts. As you can see, I had to add the `Types.LoggingMiddleware` to all the routes in the controller. Just wondering if there's a way to say to use it globally for all routes (or at least once per controller).